# Tkinter Error on keypress

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
c = tkinter.Canvas(window, height=400, width=600, bg='green')
mid_x = 600 / 2
mid_y = 400 / 2
window.geometry("600x400")
window.title("window")

def ship_control(event):
    pass

c.bind_all('<KeyPress-a>', ship_control)
def start():
    global ship
    rock_speed = 10
    ship = c.create_oval(mid_x, mid_y, mid_x + 20, mid_y + 20, fill='red', outline='orange')

button_start = tkinter.Button(window, text='play', command=start)
button_start.pack()
c.pack()
```

Error:

```
>>> 
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\queue.py", line 172, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '??'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1534, in __call__
    args = self.subst(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1252, in _substitute
    e.num = getint_event(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1231, in getint_event
    return int(s)
SystemError: result with error in PyObject_Call
```

How to reproduce:

Open the program, press play then press a.

I have no idea what could be wrong altough I have tried searching on google.

I tried adding prints but they don't get executed.

Does anyone know why I get the error?

Comment: this code doesnt work at all for me if i copy and paste it ... well i mean it runs with no errors... but no window opens or anything ... i spent about a minute messing with it thats about all i have time to invest ... please make a small runnable example ... keywords here are small and runnable

Comment: Strange that it doesn't open windows. I'll throw out the unused code

Comment: I too get no error and no window even with the "lean" code

Comment: When I run this code in Python3.3 I have no error, but nothing happens on clicking "a" (that's all right, there is a pass statement). What is supposed to happen because there are no problems with "play"-button?

Comment: I'm using 3.5.0a2 maybe that is te problem? On pressing a it gives the error for me.

Comment: You could try the code from 25.1.2.2 from official docs [link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter) and modify your code correspondently. I would add the line `window.mainloop()` to set the eternal loop.

Comment: Your code can't possibly give the error you say it does. The error mentions `rpc.request_queue` but your code has no `rpc` object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using 3.5 instead of 3.4. Switching versions worked.